# How to use Radio Buttons and select fields XOR in a form, in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that has 8 selectable radio buttons for an attribute :mvp, and a select drop-down menu at the end. I want the user to be able to press a radio button for one of the corresponding values, or not select a radio button and pick an option from the select drop-down menu. They can't both select a radio button and an option from the select field. Here's my code. Please advise.

**HTML**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.awards.build) do |f| %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Stephen Curry' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Lebron James' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Kevin Durant' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Russell Westbrook' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Kawhi Leonard' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Karl-Anthony Towns' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Chris Paul' %>
<%= f.select :mvp, ['Al Horford', 'Al Jefferson', 'Andre Drummond', 'Andre Igoudala','Andrew Wiggins', 'Anthony Davis', 'Austin Rivers', 'Ben Simmons', 'Blake Griffin', 'Brook Lopez', 'Carmelo Anthony', 'Chandler Parsons','Chris Bosh', 'Damian Lillard', 'Deandre Jordan', 'Demar Derozan', 'Demarcus Cousins', 'Derrick Favors', 'Dirk Nowitzki', 'Draymond Green', 'Dwight Howard', 'Dwyane Wade', 'Eric Bledsoe', 'Giannis Antetokounmpo', 'Greg Monroe', 'Goran Dragic', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Harrison Barnes','Hassan Whiteside', 'Isaiah Thomas', 'Jahlil Okafor', 'James Harden', 'James Jones','Jeff Teague', 'Jimmy Butler', 'John Wall', 'Kemba Walker','Kevin Love', 'Khris Middleton', 'Klay Thompson', 'Kristaps Porzingis', 'Kyle Lowry', 'Kyrie Irving', 'Lamarcus Aldridge', 'Marc Gasol', 'Mike Conley', 'Nerlens Noel', 'Nicolas Batum', 'Nikola Pekovic', 'Pau Gasol', 'Paul George', 'Paul Millsap','Ricky Rubio','Rudy Gobert', 'Victor Oladipo', 'Zach Lavine'],  include_blank: "Select One" %>
<%= f.submit "Submit Pick" %>
```

As of now if I try to fill in the form, no matter what option I press in the radio buttons, the value that always gets submitted is the one in the select box. I've added an include_blank: option at the end of the select field, but then the value that gets submitted is just a blank value. So for some reason, the default submission is whatever is picked in the select field.

Comment: ok, that because you have same *name* for the radio button and select tag. You need to have uniq name, otherwise last one *wins* always.

Comment: @ArupRakshit wow that makes sense, how do I do a different name? The :mvp is the attribute the value is being submitted for in my form. How would I give them a custom tag?

Comment: Give different name and then inside the controller do a `if else` check, and assign those custom name values to actual attribute. U need to write like 2-3 lines of code to make a decision and adjust the param before send them to AR to create/update. clear now? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I don't know how efficient it is to make attributes that are pretty much useless for controllers except in certain scenarios, but whatever. I generated a new attribute using "rails g migration add_mvp_select_to_controller mvp_select:string" and then raked my database. I added the following code to the create action in the controller

```
def create
  @awardprediction = current_user.awardpredictions.build(prediction_create_params)
  if @awardprediction.mvp_select.present? && @awardprediction.mvp.present?
    flash[:alert] = "Your Award prediction could not be saved. Please make sure to only select valid input."
  elsif @awardprediction.mvp_select.present?
    @awardprediction.mvp = @awardprediction.mvp_select
    @awardprediction.mvp_select = nil
  end
  unless @awardprediction.save 
    flash[:alert] = "Your Award prediction could not be saved. Please make sure to only select valid input."
  end       
    redirect_to :back

end
```

and then added the following to my model to validate XOR

```
validate :mvp_xor_mvp_select
def mvp_xor_mvp_select
        unless mvp.blank? ^ mvp_select.blank?
            errors.add(:base, "Why are you trying to cheat")
        end
end
```

and then of course, changed the attribute on the select field to :mvp_select